# python miniconda install sklearn but not found it

Tags: python

To install sklearn, I installed miniconda in my win10 computer, and in the Anaconda command line, I input:

```
(C:\Python\Miniconda3) C:\Users\apple>conda install sklearn
```

and it shows that install successfully

```
 (C:\Python\Miniconda3) C:\Users\apple>conda install scikit-learn
 Fetching package metadata ...........
 Solving package specifications: .

 # All requested packages already installed.
 # packages in environment at C:\Python\Miniconda3:
 #
 scikit-learn              0.18.1              np113py36_1
```

There are python 2.7 and python 3.6 in my computer, and the default environment is python 3.6. However, I found that there is no sklearn in my python 3.6, when I input this order in python 3.6 command line:

```
 Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 
bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

and I input the same order in python 2.7 command line, there is also:

```
>>> import sklearn

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

however in conda command line, it shows the sklearn has been installed successfully.

Could you please tell me the reason and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** It is normally inadvisable to have multiple installations of Python; use virtual environments instead if you require the use of different Python versions.

First, check which python version are you using in the command prompt.

```
python --verison
```

It should display `Miniconda` somewhere in your version information. If not, then it would mean that your `python` is executing in a different path. You would have to set the `PATH` variable to point to the location where the Miniconda executables are stored.

**Explanation:**

Usually, when a fresh installation takes place in Windows, the path for the executables is *appended* to the `PATH` variable. Using `conda` would use the Miniconda (or Anaconda) executables because the normal Python installation would not contain it. If you have multiple installations, your `python` command would point to the executables of the distribution initially installed and not Miniconda (where you have successfully installed `sklearn`).

You would have to go to the **Environment Variables** settings to change the order of the installation.